# Django CBV - dealing with optional parameters in URLs

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I have a Class Based View to list animals from a specific herd. There are multiple herds, so the user can either see all animals from ONE herd, or all animals from ALL herds.

How do I have an optional URL parameter and handle it in the CBV?

urls:

```
url(r'list/(?P<hpk>[0-9]+)/$', AnimalList.as_view(), name = 'animal_list'),
url(r'list/$', AnimalList.as_view(), name = 'animal_list'),
```

My view:

```
class AnimalList(ListView):
  model = Animal

  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs is None:
      return Animal.objects.all()
    return Animal.objects.filter(herd = self.kwargs['hpk']) # <--- line 19 that returns an error
```

Going to a URL of like `/animals/list/3/` works fine, while `/animals/list/` fails with an error. Here's that error:

```
KeyError at /animals/list/
'hpk'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/animals/list/
Django Version: 1.8.2
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'hpk'
Exception Location: /var/www/registry/animals/views.py in get_queryset, line 19
```

I get that the `self.kwargs` is a dictionary, and when I `print()` it inside the view, it'll show it's empty. But I can't figure out how to capture that scenario. I feel like this is a simple, stupid error I'm missing.

Answer (score 2):

To anyone who may stumble on this and need an answer, here is my working code after figuring it out:

```
class AnimalList(ListView):
  model = Animal

  def get_queryset(self):
    if 'hpk' in self.kwargs:
      return Animal.objects.filter(herd = self.kwargs['hpk'])
    return Animal.objects.all()
```

Essentially we test to see if the URL parameter `hpk` is present in the list of `self.kwargs`. If it is, we filter the queryset. Otherwise, we return all animals.

Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

I would implement this using GET parameters instead of separate URLs. With this approach, there is only one URL `/list/` that is filtered by parameters, for example `/list/?hpk=1`.

This is more flexible as you can eventually add more queries `/list/?hpk=1&origin=europe`

```
#url(r'list/$', AnimalList.as_view(), name = 'animal_list'),

class AnimalList(ListView):
    model = Animal

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Animal.objects.all()
        hpk = self.request.GET.get("hpk"):
        if hpk:
            try:
                queryset = queryset.filter(herd=hpk)
            except:
                # Display error message
        return queryset
```

Comment: Is the only advantage here the flexibility in further queries?

Comment: Your solution works but in my experience this one leads to cleaner code. Also if you use google analytics you problably don't want different urls for the same thing.